# Confusion between header file macro declaration and pre-processor macro declaration

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, typedef

I am new to C, so please help me with an answer before downvoting, it will help me a lot.
The definition of header file states that-

> A header file consists of C function declaration and macro definitions to be shared between different files.

And the definition of `C Preprocessor` states that-

> The C preprocessor is a macro preprocessor that transforms your program before it is compiled.All preprocessor directives begin with the `#` symbol.

My question is the `macro declaration` are done using `#` symbol in a program, does it depend on inclusion or exclusion of any header file, also how to find whether a particular file has a pre-defined macro declaration in it.
For example-
Say a file 'ani.h' has a macro declaration,
`#define anii 2`
So, once I include this file, I am allowed to use the `CNAME` i.e. `anii`directly?

Comment: Can we define macros for example `#define a 2` without including any header files? Also, what does it mean that a header file has `macro declarations` in it?

Comment: I don't think that's a particularly good definition of a header file. Where did you get it?

Comment: [link](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Header-Files.html)

Comment: No, preprocessor macros do not need to be defined in a header file.

Comment: So, it means we can use a simple `macro declaration` like `#define blah 2` without using any header file? @FredLarson

Comment: Absolutely. It's very common.

Comment: Your link says "*Including a header file produces the same results as copying the header file into each source file that needs it.*" So yes, you can just define macros wherever.

Comment: Also,I am confused what does this line means `A header file is a file containing C declarations and macro definitions (see Macros) to be shared between several source files.`It confuses me with macro declarations of pre-processor. Hope so you understand what I am trying to say.

Comment: I'm not sure how to make it any clearer than what it says.

Comment: "*confuses me*" so as you already seem to know the site. Just read all here: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/index.html#Top  and below. :)

Comment: `#include` is just another pre-processor directive as `#define` is. Those two are not related in any way. Both (as [all others](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/cpp/Index-of-Directives.html#Index-of-Directives) as well) can be used in any kind of file.

Answer (score 0):

Although they can be used to do some nice metaprogramming tricks as well as conditional programming, macros most basic use is to make programmers lives easier via syntactic sugaring. Before compiling your code, the preprocessor module will substitute all the macros by the terms they represent, so everything you define must have been declared somewhere above the point where the macro is **first used.** So if you do:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define MY_MACRO(x) for(int i=0; i<(x); ++i) printf("%d\n", func((x),i);

int func(int n, int m) {return pow(n, m);}

int main()
{
    int a = 10;
    MY_MACRO(a)
    return 0;
}
```

The preprocessor will substitute all occurrences of MY_MACRO in your code by the loop that was defined after it. The code will then be sent to compilation. When the compiler reaches the line where the macro is used, it is necessary that *printf* and *func* are declared somewhere above this line, just as if you were writing the code without the macro. (Note that *printf* and *pow* are declared in the headers included before the definition and *func* is declared after the definition, but them three are declared before the first use of the macro.)

In what concerns to knowing which macros are declared inside some lib and which aren't, I believe the only way is to check the header files you are using or to read their documentation. But if you know that some specific macro may or may not be declared, you can test it using the code below:

```
#ifdef SOME_MACRO
printf("SOME_MACRO defined!\n");
#else
printf("SOME_MACRO not defined!\n");
#endif
```

Comment: So, in simple language, we can say that we can define macros without using any header file, but if in the macro definition any functions like `printf`, `scanf` etc. are being used so we must include a header library above them.

Comment: Yes. A header for them, or a declaration if they are variables/functions you've created. in " #define VAR myVar ", myVar must have already been declared when the compiler hits the first use of VAR in the code.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier if you look at this form the view of what the pre-processor actually does.

It reads a file and replaces text and then output a new file. The new file is sent to the compiler. The pre-proc knows nothing about C code, its just a text manipulation engine

```
#include xxxx
```

says, 'replace this line by the contents of that file'

```
#define FOO BAR
```

says, 'whenever you see FOO replace it by BAR

There are also some simple conditionals: `#if` etc

A macro is simply a FOO BAR replacement, usually FOO is small and BAR is large.